# How do I use else in list comprehension for the case that no elements in one list are found in another?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

Working on the Hackerrank Sparse Arrays challenge, I have two lists of strings, S and Q. For each element of Q, I need to count the number of matching strings in S. I nearly have this working, but I would like to use an else statement to account for the case in which there are no matching strings found. Below, is the code I have, and from looking at other stack questions on the topic, its unclear to me why this doesn't work (there's a syntax error at else, but otherwise all counting is done correctly), though it seems like I might need to parenthise a particular portion of the if else statement.

```
res=[S.count(s) for s in Q if s in S else 0]
```

Comment: For future reference, if you're getting an error, please include it in your question. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit tangled, that's all. You need:

```
res=[S.count(s) if s in S else 0 for s in Q]
```

But you don't actually need that, fyi - you can just do

```
res=[S.count(s) for s in Q]
```

or even just

```
res = list(map(S.count, Q)]
```

if you want to be fancy.

You'll get 0 for any values in Q that aren't in S.

Comment: Ah, beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: @ANEF - Thank me by accepting the answer :) This will also help other people looking for questions to answer skip this one.